# Merge rows and columns in android Gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am doing an image viewing page in android.I need to merge rows in some places and merge columns in some places.Can we do it in gridview. If we select any merged image the total imageview should be selected.Please anyone tell me a suggestion. 
         Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we do it in gridview

No, sorry, `GridView` does not really support row or column spans. `GridLayout` does, though, and `TableLayout`/`TableRow` supports column spans.

You might also look at [the open source `StaggeredGridView`](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/).

Comment: StaggeredGridView is not there now.

Comment: @Arunkumar: There are many [grid libraries available](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/41) now, and `RecyclerView` can also handle this.

Answer (score 5):

Try [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView). I wrote it myself :)