# how to make two different number of columns in one gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to make a gridview having two different number of columns.

Actually my gridview is having 2 columns as `fig1` and at position 5 number of columns should be 1 as `fig2`.

I am attaching my screenshot for more clarification,

//fig1 : current output

[image: current output]

//fig2 : final output

[image: final output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the following construction of your UI: Construct one ListView with verticle orientation (or GridView with a single column) and put in it a GridView with two columns for the first 2 rows, an ImageView (orsomething else for the purple view) and one more GridView with two columns for the last row (Sports and Arts).

Or use GridLayout and merge columns if you need the whole row to be a single column [Merge rows and columns in android Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217266/merge-rows-and-columns-in-android-gridview)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [AsymmetricGridView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1186)
I have wrote an example, to help you solve your problem.
**Result will be same as on *fig2*, but without images**

---

In your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
}
```

In your `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"/>
```

In your `DemoAdapter.java` file:

```
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.app.model.DemoItem;

import java.util.List;

    public interface DemoAdapter extends ListAdapter {

      void appendItems(List<DemoItem> newItems);

      void setItems(List<DemoItem> moreItems);
    }
```

In your `DefaultListAdapter.java` file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.app.R;
import com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.app.model.DemoItem;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Sample adapter implementation extending from AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<DemoItem> This is the
 * easiest way to get started.
 */
public class DefaultListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DemoItem> implements DemoAdapter {

  private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public DefaultListAdapter(Context context, List<DemoItem> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  public DefaultListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NotNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;

    DemoItem item = getItem(position);
    boolean isRegular = getItemViewType(position) == 0;

    if (convertView == null) {
      v = layoutInflater.inflate(
          isRegular ? R.layout.adapter_item : R.layout.adapter_item_odd, parent, false);
    } else {
      v = convertView;
    }

    TextView textView;
    if (isRegular) {
      textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    } else {
      textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_odd);
    }

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPosition()));

    return v;
  }

  @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  }

  public void appendItems(List<DemoItem> newItems) {
    addAll(newItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public void setItems(List<DemoItem> moreItems) {
    clear();
    appendItems(moreItems);
  }
}
```

In your `adapter_item.xml`:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

In your `adapter_item_odd.xml` file:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview_odd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#007bbb"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

In your `DemoItem.java` file:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.model.AsymmetricItem;

public class DemoItem implements AsymmetricItem {

  private int columnSpan;
  private int rowSpan;
  private int position;

  public DemoItem() {
    this(1, 1, 0);
  }

  public DemoItem(int columnSpan, int rowSpan, int position) {
    this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
    this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
    this.position = position;
  }

  public DemoItem(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
  }

  @Override public int getColumnSpan() {
    return columnSpan;
  }

  @Override public int getRowSpan() {
    return rowSpan;
  }

  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s: %sx%s", position, rowSpan, columnSpan);
  }

  @Override public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    columnSpan = in.readInt();
    rowSpan = in.readInt();
    position = in.readInt();
  }

  @Override public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(columnSpan);
    dest.writeInt(rowSpan);
    dest.writeInt(position);
  }

  /* Parcelable interface implementation */
  public static final Parcelable.Creator<DemoItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DemoItem>() {

    @Override public DemoItem createFromParcel(@NonNull Parcel in) {
      return new DemoItem(in);
    }

    @Override @NonNull public DemoItem[] newArray(int size) {
      return new DemoItem[size];
    }
  };
}
```

In your `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private AsymmetricGridView listView;
  private DemoAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      adapter = new DefaultListAdapter(this, getMoreItems(50));
    } else {
      adapter = new DefaultListAdapter(this);
    }

    listView.setRequestedColumnCount(2);
    listView.setRequestedHorizontalSpacing(Utils.dpToPx(this, 3));
    listView.setAdapter(getNewAdapter());
    listView.setDebugging(true);
  }

  private AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<?> getNewAdapter() {
    return new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
  }

  private List<DemoItem> getMoreItems(int qty) {
    List<DemoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    DemoItem item = new DemoItem(1, 1, 0);
    DemoItem item1 = new DemoItem(1, 1, 1);
    DemoItem item2 = new DemoItem(1, 1, 2);
    DemoItem item3 = new DemoItem(1, 1, 3);
    DemoItem item4 = new DemoItem(2, 2, 4);
    DemoItem item5 = new DemoItem(1, 1, 5);
    DemoItem item6 = new DemoItem(1, 1, 6);

    items.add(item);
    items.add(item1);
    items.add(item2);
    items.add(item3);
    items.add(item4);
    items.add(item5);
    items.add(item6);

    return items;
  }
}
```